# Bower ignores my .bowerrc

Tags: bower

I'm trying to use bower for the first time, I've got a .bowerrc that reads:

```
{
  "directory": "www/components",
  "json": "config/bower.json"
}
```

but for some reason it seems to ignore it. When executing bower install in this folder nothing happens, whereas when I swap into the 'config' folder and run it again, it correctly installs the packages (albeit in the wrong relative location).

Why might `.bowerrc` be ignored?

Answer (score 4):

As per the current configuration mentioned in [Configuration Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.4pzytc1f9j8k), `.bowerrc` doesn't support `json` property.

So, we need to have `bower.json` file to issue `bower install` in the current folder.

How about creating a Symbolic Link of `bower.json` from `config` folder to the root folder and ignoring this link in SVN/GIT. Definitely it is not a good idea but to keep all configuration files in a separate config folder you may try it. Also this extra step is needed for new users while setting up the environment.